# AnalysisException: Parquet type not supported: INT32 (UINT_32) in Scala

Tags: scala, parquet, ioexception

when am accessing my source parquet for particular folder am getting below error

Caused by: IOException: Could not read or convert schema for file: //XXX/20220814/xxx.parquet
Caused by: AnalysisException: Parquet type not supported: INT32 (UINT_32)